# Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately

Tags: configuration, linux, error, ubuntu, log

Just glanced at my logs and noticed 50+ messages like this from tor. What exactly do these messages mean? I don't think I was using tor at the time the messages occurred. What might've invoked them?

```
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:34 hostname Tor[17074]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Nov 17 10:03:36 hostname Tor[17074]: We now have enough directory information to build circuits.
Nov 17 10:03:37 hostname Tor[17074]: Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Nov 17 10:03:37 hostname Tor[17074]: Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.


# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

# tor --version
Tor version 0.3.1.8 (git-868c1b2b1eb7225a).
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens when it can not parse the following two files:

- GEOIP IPv4 file at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\[username]\geoip`
- GEOIP IPv6 file at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\[username]\geoip6`